# Authorize works in postman but not in the browser | Asp.net core 3.1 & jwt

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt

When i make requests with token by `Postman` works very good but when i do it by the browser (Angular) i get the status code `404`

By postman

```
Request Headers

Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJuYW1laWQiOiJwdXB5IGZyaWFzIiwibmJmIjoxNjUyMDY1NzczLCJleHAiOjE2NTIwNjU4MzMsImlhdCI6MTY1MjA2NTc3M30.4mdgD-wbcwYb0nNKUYqEZJwhWKiixDhFRgdffW4QEs4
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.29.0
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 946f36f4-c1a1-4013-94bc-3bbebfeb452a
Host: localhost:59573
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive

Status Code: 200 OK
```

By browser

```
Request Headers

Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: es-US,es;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,es-419;q=0.6
Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJuYW1laWQiOiJwdXB5IGZyaWFzIiwibmJmIjoxNjUyMDY1NzczLCJleHAiOjE2NTIwNjU4MzMsImlhdCI6MTY1MjA2NTc3M30.4mdgD-wbcwYb0nNKUYqEZJwhWKiixDhFRgdffW4QEs4
Connection: keep-alive
Host: localhost:59573
Origin: http://localhost:4200
Referer: http://localhost:4200/
sec-ch-ua: " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="101", "Google Chrome";v="101"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.54 Safari/537.36

Status Code: 404 Not Found
```

This is the `Startup`

```
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Configuration.GetValue<string>("SecretKey"));

           
            services.AddAuthentication(auth =>
            {
                auth.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                auth.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                auth.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            }).AddJwtBearer(jwtB =>
            {
                jwtB.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                jwtB.SaveToken = true;
                jwtB.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false
                };
            });


            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("AllowWebApp", policy =>
                policy.AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()

                );
            });

            services.AddDbContext<contextItem>(options =>
            {
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("EFConnection"));
            });

            services.AddControllers();

        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseCors("AllowWebApp");
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
```

Generating the token

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Post(UserLogin data)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            User user = await _context._User.Where(i => i.User_Name == data.User_name).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

            if (user == null)
            {
                return NotFound("User doesn't exist");
            }

            if (data.Password != user.Password)
            {
                return new ObjectResult("Invalid Password") { StatusCode = 403 };
            }
            else
            {
                var secretKey = _configuration.GetValue<string>("SecretKey");
                var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(secretKey);

                var claims = new ClaimsIdentity();
                claims.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Name));

                var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
                {
                    Subject = claims,
                    Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(1),
                    SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)

                };

                var tokenHadler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
                var createdToken = tokenHadler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
                string bearerToken = tokenHadler.WriteToken(createdToken);

                return Ok(bearerToken);

            }
        }
```

The controller

```
    [Authorize]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]

    public class ItemsController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly contextItem _context;

        public ItemsController(contextItem context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<object>> GetItem(int id)
        {
            var item = await Task.Run(() => _context.Item.FromSqlRaw($"EXEC SP_GET_ONE @ID={id}").AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault());

            if (item == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return item;
        }
    }
```

Comment: 404 has nothing to do with sending tokens. seems to be calling the wrong url

Comment: @MohammadAghazadeh  thanks, i deleted an `s` of the url without to want, i just type it again and it works